# GLSL Rounded Rectangle Corners Are Stretched

Tags: opengl, glsl, rounded-corners

I'm programing a GUI library in openGL and decided to add rounded corners because I feel like it gives a much more professional look to the units.
I've implemented the common

```
length(max(abs(p) - b, 0.0)) - radius
```

method and it almost works perfectly except for the fact tat the corners seems as though they are stretched:

[image]

My fragment shader:

```
in vec2 passTexCoords;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform int width;
uniform int height;
uniform int radius;    

void main() {
    fragment = color;

    vec2 pos = (abs(passTexCoords - 0.5) + 0.5) * vec2(width, height);

    float alpha = 1.0 - clamp(length(max(pos - (vec2(width, height) - radius), 0.0)) - radius, 0.0, 1.0);

    fragment.a = alpha;
}
```

The stretching does make sense to me but when I replace with

```
vec2 pos = (abs(passTexCoords - 0.5) + 0.5) * vec2(width, height) * vec2(scaleX, scaleY);
```

and

```
float alpha = 1.0 - clamp(length(max(pos - (vec2(width, height) * vec2(scaleX, scaleY) - radius), 0.0)) - radius, 0.0, 1.0);
```

(where scaleX and scaleY are scalars between 0.0 and 1.0 that represent the width and height of the rectangle relative to the screen) the rectangle almost completely disappears:

[image]

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to figure out (and mark with a comment) which coordinate system each of your vectors is supposed to be in.

Comment: Camera coordinates? Window pixel coordinates? Or are you using a custom coordinate system?

Comment: Alright. passTexCoord is just the corners of the rectangle in texel space (0.0 - 1.0). width and height are the width and height of the screen in pixels. radius is also in pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `passTexCoords` is a a texture coordinate in range [0, 1]. And that `width` and `height` is the size of the screen. And `scaleX` and `scaleY` is the ration of the green area to the size of the screen.
Calculate the absolute position (`pos`) of the current fragment in relation to the center of the green area in pixel units:

```c
vec2 pos = (abs(passTexCoords - 0.5) + 0.5) * vec2(width*scaleX, height*scaleY);
```

Calculate the distance from the center point of the arc, to the current fragment:

```c
vec2 arc_cpt_vec = max(pos - vec2(width*scaleX, height*scaleY) + radius, 0.0);
```

If the length of the vector is greater than the radius, then the fragment has to be skipped:

```c
float alpha = length(arc_cpt_vec) > radius ? 0.0 : 1.0;
```

Comment: Well that's what I coded already. (avoiding the if statement and making a smooth transition) My problem is that (in your case) the pos variable is somehow stretched

Comment: No width and height are the pixel size of the screen as mentioned in my question and comment

Comment: I do have that information as mentioned in my question in the form of scaleX and scaleY

Comment: I did that as mentioned in the question and it makes most of the rectangle disappear except for a little stripe at the top and bottom

Comment: @J.Lengel That is not verifiable for me. I can not confirm. Are you sure that `scaleX` and especially `scaleY` are positive values? Try `scaleY=0.5;` `scaleY=0.5;` in the fragment shader to verify that. Do you calculate the scale factors by a division of integral values?

Comment: it might actually be that they are negative. I have just left my home so i cant test this but will be back in an hour and a half or so to test that. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Alright! It worked. I had changed this but it still didn't work so I basically rewrote most of the shader and it worked! Thanks for guiding me everyone

Comment: I have a constraint system in place where each of the components has a north, east, south and west constraint. To render the quad, I convert these values to offset and scale values but had my y-coordinates(north and south) flipped so that the scale.y was always negative causing strange behaviour in the length function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the distances are not scaled into screen space, and are therefore stretched across the greatest window axis as a result. You can fix this if you multiply the normalized position by the aspect ratio of the screen, along with the other parameters for the box. I wrote an example on [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wsKGzW) that does this:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Input info
    vec2 boxPos; // The position of the center of the box (in normalized coordinates)
    vec2 boxBnd; // The half-bounds (radii) of the box (in normalzied coordinates)
    float radius;// Radius


    boxPos = vec2(0.5, 0.5);    // center of the screen
    boxBnd = vec2(0.25, 0.25);  // half of the area
    radius = 0.1;

    // Normalize the pixel coordinates (this is "passTexCoords" in your case)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // (Note: iResolution.xy holds the x and y dimensions of the window in pixels)
    vec2 aspectRatio = vec2(iResolution.x/iResolution.y, 1.0);

    // In order to make sure visual distances are preserved, we multiply everything by aspectRatio
    uv *= aspectRatio;
    boxPos *= aspectRatio;
    boxBnd *= aspectRatio;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));

    // Output to screen
    float alpha = length(max(abs(uv - boxPos) - boxBnd, 0.0)) - radius;

    // Shadertoy doesn't have an alpha in this case
    if(alpha <= 0.0){
        fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
    }else{
        fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}
```

There may be a less computationally expensive way to do this, but this was a simple solution I cooked up.

Comment: The issue with this example is that the aspectratio messes up my exact positioning of the box. The way i position my boxes is done very precisly and i think aspectratio will mess that up. Most of the boxes are defined by pixels (which update according to the width and height of the screen of course)

Comment: Well, you could simply transfer the pixel coordinates into normalized space by dividing the position by the width and height of the screen. The transformation would be consistent, and I doubt the precision loss would be noticeable. Alternatively, you could also describe everything in pixel coordinates instead, and tweak all of the operations accordingly.

Comment: also i dont completely understand your algorithm for rounding the corners. could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. The rounding of the corners is determined by `float alpha = length(max(abs(uv - boxPos) - boxBnd, 0.0)) - radius`; `uv` is the position of the pixel, which is translated by `boxPos`, and `boxBnd` is the dimensions of the rectangle. This expression returns a [2d signed distance](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm); if this distance is less than or equal to 0, it is considered inside of the figure.

Comment: I might take a look at this again in the future but for now I have a fix. Thank you for your answer anyways!